# Trying to run a HTML application but server could not find right bundle

Tags: html, eclipse, server

I tried to run a HTML file that I coded on netbeans in eclipse. I downloaded the web tools platform in the eclipse marketplace. Then I configured the server but when I tried to run the file, I got a popup box with an error saying:

'Starting J2EE Preview at localhost' has encountered a problem. Could not find the required bundle org.eclipse.jetty.webapp. Does anyone know where I could get this bundle. I have eclipse luna.

Comment: Its simple, Don't use eclipse